# Calling stored procedure with OUTPUT parameter in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, output, dynamic-sql

I am calling a stored procedure with `OUTPUT` parameter using dynamic SQL.

```
set @cSql='EXEC '+@cName+'.dbo.uspNDateGet '''
    +convert(varchar(10),@dtAsOn,102)+''','''
    +@cBr+''','''
    +@cLCode+''','''
    +convert(varchar(10),@dtNDate,102)+''' OUTPUT'

exec(@cSql)
```

On executing the script, I get following error.

> Cannot use the `OUTPUT` option when passing a constant to a stored procedure.

Without using dynamic SQL, the script gives me the required result.

```
EXEC uspNDateGet @dtAsOn,@cBr,@cLCode,@dtNDate OUTPUT
```

Comment: Declare that output variable inside dynamic query. Use sp_executesql with passing parameters. Look for output from dynamic sql

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass parameters from outside into the inside query.

Here I show you the generic case:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

declare @Out1 nvarchar(10);
declare @Out2 nvarchar(10);

declare @ParmDef nvarchar(max);

set @ParmDef = 
      '  @Parm_Out1 nvarchar(10) '
    + ', @Parm_Out2 nvarchar(10) ' ;

set @sql='EXEC myproc @Parm_Out1 OUTPUT, @Parm_Out2 OUTPUT '

exec sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDef, @Parm_Out1 = @Out1, @Parm_Out2 = @Out2
```

Answer (score 0):

**In this *particular* instance, you don't actually need dynamic SQL at all.**

You can parameterize the name of the stored procedure being called with `EXEC`, and pass the parameters normally. [This is documented here:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)

```sql
DECLARE @dtNDate datetime, @procName nvarchar(386);

SET @ProcName = @cName + N'.dbo.uspNDateGet';

EXEC @procName
  @dtAsOn = @dtAsOn,
  @cBr = @cBr,
  @cLCode = @cLCode,
  @dtNDate = @dtNDate OUTPUT
```